# saga watcher and typescript issue

Tags: redux-saga

having a typescript problem defining multiple sagas in a watcher, i see the pattern a lot:

```
// foo.JS
export function *fooSagas() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery("FOO_A", fooASaga),
    takeEvery("FOO_B", fooBSaga),
  ]);
}
```

but when I try to do this in a typescript file I get the following:

```
// foo.TS
export function *fooSagas() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery("FOO_A", fooASaga),
    /* 
      all subsequent calls throw this typescript error: 
      The last overload gave the following error.
      Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>
      effects.d.ts(291, 17): The last overload is declared here.
    */
    takeEvery("FOO_B", fooBSaga),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

posting so that I hopefuly save someone else time... 
apparently it's just typescript throwing up.

added // @ts-ignore before each line and everything works

```
    yield all ([
      // @ts-ignore      
      takeLatest(ACT.todo.saga.create, create),
      // @ts-ignore      
      takeLatest(ACT.todo.saga.retrieve, retrieve),
      // @ts-ignore      
      takeLatest(ACT.todo.saga.update,update),
      // @ts-ignore      
      takeLatest(ACT.todo.saga.delete,del),
      // @ts-ignore      
      takeLatest(ACT.todo.saga.list, list)     
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find a better answer here
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1883
in the comment from chenghw on Jul 9, 2019.

> In the  generator, you are currently declaring the action as `{ payload: ICredential }`without a type. If you declare the type, I think you will get rid of that error...so something like this...`{ type: typeof types.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST; payload: ICredential; }`

Comment: Links to resources outside StackOverflow are generally discouraged.